# MUI: The `anchorEl` prop provided to the component is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I m building a React 18.2 app using MUI 5.10.5, but I have run into a problem creating a `<Menu />` element that opens in response to a button click. The menu appears, but it seems the `anchorEl` is not configured properly, because the menu appears in the top-left of the screen and the browser console has this complaint:

[image: Screenshot of browser console]

The issue is complicated by the fact that the menus pertain to each row in a `<Table />` so, besides anything else, I am not sure if I am supposed to have a single menu outside the table, or repeat the menu for each row in the table. Which seems expensive. But I have organised the code so that the menu is currently duplicated.

```
export const MetricsQuery = () => {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState<{
    open: boolean;
    anchorEl: null | Element;
  }>({open: false, anchorEl: null});

  const handleOpenMenuClick = ({currentTarget}: MouseEvent) =>
    setMenuState({open: true, anchorEl: currentTarget});

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <StyledTable>
        {/*Header*/}
        <TableBody>
          {queryMetrics.map((row: QueryMetric) => (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.locationName}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.deviceName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.pointName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Stack>
                  <IconButton
                    id="basic-button"
                    aria-controls={menuState.open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded={menuState.open ? 'true' : undefined}
                    onClick={handleOpenMenuClick}
                  >
                    <MoreVertIcon sx={{color: theme.palette.primary.light}} fontSize="small"/>
                  </IconButton>
                  <Menu
                    anchorEl={menuState.anchorEl}
                    open={menuState.open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    MenuListProps={{
                      'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button'
                    }}
                  >
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Remove</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Disable</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Pin to Top</MenuItem>
                  </Menu>
                </Stack>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </StyledTable>
    </TableContainer>
  )
}
```

I have tried quite a number of configurations; such as

- omitting the ID of the `<IconButton />`
- making this ID unique for each row
- having a single menu outside of the `<StyledTable />`
- following the [menu documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/) more literally

Not sure what else to try..suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if I am supposed to have a single menu outside the table, or repeat the menu for each row in the table.

You can have just one `Menu` outside of the table.  The `anchorEl` will determine where it is positioned.

You can also have a `Menu` for every table row, as it will not be rendered to the DOM when it is closed.  The advantage of this approach is that each menu can transition independently, so that one can animate closed while another animates open. But if you want to do it this way then you will need a separate `menuState` for each row, as they all have their own anchors.

What you have right now will open many copies of the same menu, all on top of each other, when any one of the buttons is clicked.

I would move the button and its menu into a new component so that you can have a separate state for each.

```
const RowMenu = ({ id }: QueryMetric) => {
  const [menuState, setMenuState] = useState<{
    open: boolean;
    anchorEl: null | Element;
  }>({ open: false, anchorEl: null });

  const handleOpenMenuClick = ({ currentTarget }: { currentTarget: Element }) =>
    setMenuState({ open: true, anchorEl: currentTarget });

  const handleClose = () => {
    setMenuState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, open: false }));
  };

  const menuId = `basic-menu-${id}`;
  const buttonId = `basic-button-${id}`;

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton
        id={buttonId}
        aria-controls={menuState.open ? menuId : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={menuState.open ? "true" : undefined}
        onClick={handleOpenMenuClick}
        sx={{ alignSelf: "center" }}
      >
        <MoreVertIcon
          sx={{ color: (theme) => theme.palette.primary.light }}
          fontSize="small"
        />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id={menuId}
        anchorEl={menuState.anchorEl}
        open={menuState.open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": buttonId
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Remove</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Disable</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Pin to Top</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </>
  );
};

export const MetricsQuery = () => {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <StyledTable>
        {/*Header*/}
        <TableBody>
          {queryMetrics.map((row) => (
            <TableRow key={row.id}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.locationName}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.deviceName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{row.pointName}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Stack>
                  <RowMenu {...row} />
                </Stack>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </StyledTable>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-menus-28kppz?file=/src/App.tsx)

> making this ID unique for each row

If you have `id`s in your DOM then they need to be unique.  Your aria attributes don't make sense if they are all the same.  But this is a separate issue and I don't think that this would cause any of the issues that you are having with anchor elements.